# How to group list of Tuples with 3 items where element.item3 == element2.item2

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting, grouping

I have the following problem: Need to group a `List<Tuple<object, int, int>>` where the item3 is equal to item2 for the different elements and if there are any that do not match they should stay at the current position!
To be more specific `List<Tuple<UserDescription, userId, inviterId>>`

I have tried different ways with LINQ - group by, select, where, but without success....

```
var list = new List<Tuple<object, int, int>> // item2 - UserId, item3 - InviterId
    {
        new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Ivan" }, 1, 12),
        new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "George" }, 2, 3),
        new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Phil" }, 3, 12),
        new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "John" }, 4, 3),
        new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Giggs" }, 5, 1),
        new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Higgins" }, 6, 1)
    };
```

The expected result should be grouped Tuples.
Ivan should stay at the current cuz there aren't users with user id 12.
Below him should be Giggs and Higgins cuz their inviter id is 1 (user Id for Ivan) and so on. Results:

```
Ivan (user id = 1)
 Giggs (inviter id = 1)
 Higgins (inviter id = 1)
Phil (user id = 3)
 George (inviter id = 3)
 John (inviter id = 3)
```

Comment: You say that if there are any that do not match they should stay at the current position, so why does George not show as the second user with no inviter ids below? I understand how Ivan has Giggs and Higgins and Phil has George and John, but shouldn't George be between Ivan and Phil as a user, just with no one below him?

Comment: No, George should be under Phil's group cuz it has inviter id 3 which is Phil's id

Comment: So are all users excluded that don't have any inviter ids matching their user id?

Answer (score 2):

<s>Here's my attempt.</s> NOTE: This code assumes that your list indicies = UserId.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<object, int, int>> // item2 - UserId, item3 - InviterId
        {
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Ivan" }, 1, 12),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "George" }, 2, 3),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Phil" }, 3, 12),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "John" }, 4, 3),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Giggs" }, 5, 1),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Higgins" }, 6, 1)
        };

        var grouped = list.ToLookup(t => t.Item2);

        var withInviter = grouped.Select(grp => Tuple.Create(list[grp.Key], grp));

        var sorted = withInviter.OrderBy(t => t.Item1.Item2);
```

Edit: I'm sorry, but as I read your example again I see I misunderstood what results you are looking for. I seems that users can be divided into invited and not invited? I will update my answer as it's not correct.

Edit 2: This one should work:

```
    struct InviterAndInvited {
        public Tuple<object, int, int> Inviter;
        public IEnumerable<Tuple<object, int, int>> Invited;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Tuple<object, int, int>> // item2 - UserId, item3 - InviterId
        {
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Ivan" }, 1, 12),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "George" }, 2, 3),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Phil" }, 3, 12),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "John" }, 4, 3),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Giggs" }, 5, 1),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Higgins" }, 6, 1)
        };

        var byInviter = list.ToLookup(u => u.Item3);

        var inviterInveted = list
            .Where(user => byInviter.Contains(user.Item2))
            .Select(user => new InviterAndInvited() {
                Inviter = user,
                Invited = byInviter[user.Item2] 
            } );

        foreach (var grp in inviterInveted) // Print results
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grp.Inviter.Item1);
            foreach (var user in grp.Invited) {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + user.Item1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 4: Changed GetOrDefault to []

Comment: What is supposed to be GetOrDefault cuz does not work ?

Comment: @S.Minchev Sorry, I fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can group by the inviter id, then loop through the original list and match where the user id matches the inviter id like this:

```
        var list = new List<Tuple<object, int, int>> // item2 - UserId, item3 - InviterId
        {
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Ivan" }, 1, 12),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "George" }, 2, 3),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Phil" }, 3, 12),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "John" }, 4, 3),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Giggs" }, 5, 1),
            new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Higgins" }, 6, 1)
        };

        var groups = list.GroupBy(i => i.Item3);
        var groupedList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var user in list)
        {
            //I'm assuming you actually want to display / store the data as per your results
            var propInfo = user.Item1.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
            groupedList.Add(propInfo.GetValue(user.Item1, null).ToString() + " (user id = " + user.Item2 + ")");
            var group = groups.Where(grp => grp.Key == user.Item2).ToList().SelectMany(g => g);
            foreach (var inviter in group)
            {
                groupedList.Add(propInfo.GetValue(inviter.Item1, null).ToString() + " (inviter id = " + inviter.Item3 + ")");
            }
        }

        // display items in list
        foreach (var item in groupedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

This would display results like this:

[image]

Comment: The only problem with this solution is the repetitive data, but nice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution in LINQPad:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<object, int, int>> // item2 - UserId, item3 - InviterId
            {
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Ivan", Role = "Bidder" }, 1, 12),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "George", Role = "Guest" }, 2, 3),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Phil", Role = "Bidder" }, 3, 12),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "John", Role = "Guest" }, 4, 3),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Giggs", Role = "Guest" }, 5, 1),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Higgins", Role = "Guest" }, 6, 1),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Alone", Role = "Guest" }, 7, 111),
                new Tuple<object, int, int>(new { Name = "Alone2", Role = "Guest" }, 8, 112),
            };

        var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<object>>();

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(element.Item2))
            {
                dict.Add(element.Item2, new List<object> { element.Item1 });
            }
        }

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(element.Item3))
            {
                dict[element.Item3].Add(element);
            }
        }

        dict.Where(d => d.Value.Count() > 1).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful.

```
   var result = new List<Tuple<Tuple<object, int, int>,List<Tuple<object, int, int>>>>();
   list.ForEach(item => result.Add(new Tuple<Tuple<object, int, int>, List<Tuple<object, int, int>>>(new Tuple<object, int, int>(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3),  list.Where(x => x.Item3 == item.Item2).ToList())));
   result = result.Where(x => x.Item2.Count != 0).ToList();
```

*Now, result keeps the data as you want.*

**If you want to print them;**

```
  foreach(var user in result) {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Concat((string)user.Item1.Item1.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(user.Item1.Item1,null), " (user id = ", user.Item1.Item2,")"));

         foreach (var inviter in user.Item2) {
             Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("  ", (string)inviter.Item1.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(inviter.Item1, null), " (inviter id = ", inviter.Item3,")"));
         }
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
```

*The output's shown below;*

```
Ivan (user id = 1)
  Giggs (inviter id = 1)
  Higgins (inviter id = 1)
Phil (user id = 3)
  George (inviter id = 3)
  John (inviter id = 3)
```